# How to receive data from a modal?

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework

I have a modal with a select to filter regions.
When I open the modal, I select the region and show the data for that region, so I want to send that data back to the First Page. And I think I did it right, because on the CONSOLE I see the filtered data, but I do not know how to display then in my HTML on the First Page.
Can anyone help me with this? I do not know what exactly I need to do.

MODAL.TS

```
 export class FiltrosModalPage implements OnInit {
   public selectedFilter: string = 'regiao.id';
   regiao: any;
   regioes: Regiao[];
   myParam: string;
   produtos: Produto[];
   produtossubcategoria: Produtosubcategoria[];


   constructor(
     private viewController: ViewController,
     public navCtrl: NavController,
     public db: DatabaseProvider,
     public navParams: NavParams,
     public viewCtrl: ViewController
   ) {
     console.log(navParams.get('val'));
     this.regioes = navParams.get('val');
   }


   selecionaregiao(id) {
     this.db.getProdutosregiao(id)
       .then(data => this.produtos = data)
       .catch(error => console.log('Something want wrong!'));
       console.log('passou em tudo')
   }

   dismiss() {
     let data = this.produtos;
     this.viewCtrl.dismiss(data);
   }
}
```

HOME.TS

```
openFiltrosModal() {
  this.openModal('FiltrosModalPage');
}

openModal(pageName) {

  let filtrosModal = this.modalCtrl.create(pageName, {'val': this.regioes}, { cssClass: 'inset-modal' });
  filtrosModal.onDidDismiss(data => {
    console.log('MODAL DATA', data);
    this.value = data;
  });
  filtrosModal.present();
}
```

[filter optioons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jSgi7.png) [my console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TfLv9.png)

As in the console image, I'm getting this data on the first page html. But I do not know how to display then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you saved the data in a property of your class (`this.value`) you just need an [ngFor to iterate through the arrays](https://angular.io/guide/displaying-data) and display the data.

You can do as this on your HTML

```
<!-- Here you'll use the ngIf to just show the list itens if there's something on value -->
<ion-list *ngIf="value">
  <!-- ngFor'll iterate your array and render a new element for every item in your array -->
  <ion-item *ngFor="let item of value">
    <!-- then you can access an property of your object in that array position -->
    {{item.nom_regiao}}
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Be sure you `value` doesn't have any value before filtering in the modal, if it's initialized with any value the `ngIf` condition must be changed.

Comment: I'm getting lines of content, but no text or anything. but the quantity of items is right, according to the modal. But why is it devoid of content?

Comment: The property name is correct? Try `{{item.id}}`, does it show any content?